# redux-observable TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: redux-observable

I have been trying to implement [react](https://reactjs.org/) server-side-rendering using [next](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/), and i am using the [with-redux-observable-app example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-observable), the example works fine, but i would like to improve the project a little bit by doing

1. [redux modular pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)
2. [fractal project structure](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/wiki/Fractal-Project-Structure)
3. If possible, i would like to implement [stateless components](https://javascriptplayground.com/functional-stateless-components-react/)
4. Because #2, i can no longer use [react state lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), to solve that i usually took advantage of react router onEnter props, but [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/215) suggest that i should use `componentWillMount`, which doesn't meet my #2 condition

I have put the project on [github](https://github.com/littlechad/next-metron), with this particular problem committed on this [branch](https://github.com/littlechad/next-metron/tree/feature/hoc-implementation)

Here's the summary of what i did so far

to achieve #1

```
// ./redux/index.js
...

import rootEpics from './root/epics'
import rootReducers from './root/reducers'

export default function initStore(initialState) {
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpics)
  const logger = createLogger({ collapsed: true })
  const middlewares = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, epicMiddleware, logger)

  return createStore(rootReducers, initialState, middlewares)
}

// ./redux/root/epics.js
import { fetchCharacterEpic, startFetchingCharactersEpic } from '../ducks/Character/epics'

const rootEpics = combineEpics(
  fetchCharacterEpic,
  startFetchingCharactersEpic,
)

export default rootEpics

// ./redux/root/reducers.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import Character from '../ducks/Character'

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  Character,
})

export default rootReducers


// ./redux/ducks/Character/index.js
import * as types from './types'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: {},
  error: {},
  id: 1,
}

const Character = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.FETCH_CHARACTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: payload.response,
        id: state.id + 1,
      }
    case types.FETCH_CHARACTER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload.error,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default Character

// ./redux/ducks/Character/types.js
export const FETCH_CHARACTER = 'FETCH_CHARACTER'
export const FETCH_CHARACTER_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_CHARACTER_SUCCESS'
export const FETCH_CHARACTER_FAILURE = 'FETCH_CHARACTER_FAILURE'
export const START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS = 'START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS'
export const STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS = 'STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS'

// ./redux/ducks/Character/actions.js
import * as types from './types'

export const startFetchingCharacters = () => ({
  type: types.START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS,
})

export const stopFetchingCharacters = () => ({
  type: types.STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS,
})

export const fetchCharacter = id => ({
  type: types.FETCH_CHARACTER,
  payload: { id },
})

export const fetchCharacterSuccess = response => ({
  type: types.FETCH_CHARACTER_SUCCESS,
  payload: { response },
})

export const fetchCharacterFailure = error => ({
  type: types.FETCH_CHARACTER_FAILURE,
  payload: { error },
})

// ./redux/ducks/Character/epics.js
import 'rxjs'
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'
import { takeUntil, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable'
import ajax from 'universal-rx-request'

import * as actions from './actions'
import * as types from './types'

export const startFetchingCharactersEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS),
  mergeMap(() => action$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => of(actions.fetchCharacter())),
    takeUntil(ofType(types.STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS)),
  )),
)

export const fetchCharacterEpic = (action$, id) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.FETCH_CHARACTER),
  mergeMap(() => ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8010/call',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      method: 'get',
      path: `people/${id}`,
    },
  })
    .map(response => actions.fetchCharacterSuccess(
      response.body,
      true,
    ))
    .catch(error => of(actions.fetchCharacterFailure(
      error.response.body,
      false,
    )))),
)
```

to achieve #2

```
// ./pages/index/container/index.js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'

import rootEpics from '../../../redux/root/epics'
import { fetchCharacter } from '../../../redux/ducks/Character/actions'

import Index from '../component'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  id: state.Character.id,

})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  async setInitialCharacter(id) {
    const epic = of(fetchCharacter({ id }))
    const resultAction = await rootEpics(
      epic,
      id,
    ).toPromise()
    dispatch(resultAction)
  },
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)((props) => {
  props.setInitialCharacter(props.id)
  return (<Index />)
})


// ./pages/index/component/index.js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

import Info from '../container/info'

const Index = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet
      title="Ini index | Hello next.js!"
      meta={[
        { property: 'og:title', content: 'ini index title' },
        { property: 'og:description', content: 'ini index description' },
      ]}
    />
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
    <Info />
    <br />
    <nav>
      {/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
      <Link href="/other"><a>Navigate to other</a></Link><br />
      <Link href="/about"><a>Navigate to about</a></Link>
      {/* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
    </nav>
  </div>
)

export default Index


// ./pages/index/container/info.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Info from '../../../components/Info'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.Character.data,
  error: state.Character.error,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Info)
```

with those above, the fetch works fine, but...

i don't want the fetch to keep running, i want it to run just once `onEnter`.

As an attempt to achieve that, i wrote an epic called `startFetchingCharactersEpic()`, and an action called `startFetchingCharacters()`, and lastly add `mergeMap(() => of(actions.stopFetchingCharacters())),` at the end of `fetchCharacterEpic()` `pipe` arguments, with the following scenario in mind

1. dispatch actions.startFetchingCharacters(), in container
2. that will trigger `startFetchingCharactersEpic()`
3. that will do so until `types.STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS`
4. that will dispatch actions.fetchCharacter()
5. that will trigger `fetchCharacterEpic()`
6. that will dispatch actions.stopFetchingCharacters()
7. that will trigger #3

setInitialCharacter

```
// ./pages/index/container/index.js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  async setInitialCharacter(id) {
    const epic = of(startFetchingCharacters())
    const resultAction = await rootEpics(
      epic,
      id,
    ).toPromise()
    dispatch(resultAction)
  },
})
```

but by doing that i got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`, the console doesn't give me enough information than saying that the error is coming from `setInitialCharacter`

Tried googling the issue, but found nothing related to my problem

**UPDATE**

I manage to make it [work again](https://github.com/littlechad/next-metron/tree/feature/hoc-implementation) based on [@jayphelps'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1770633/jayphelps) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757269/387808) below, which brought me back to some of my original problems, which are

1. How to fully use stateless component without utilizing [react state lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), especially replacing `onEnter`
2. How to just call the `fetchCharacterEpic` just once on page load

but i guess these 2 worth another post, as i realized i am asking too many question on this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally guessing here, but it's possible that the error is coming from the fact that you're dispatching a Promise here:

```
const resultAction = await rootEpics(
  epic,
  id,
).toPromise()
dispatch(resultAction)
```

Your question doesn't mention, but that means you must have middleware that intercepts that promise since redux (and redux-observable) only expected POJOs `{ type: string }`.

It's also possible that the promise isn't resolving to anything other than `undefined`, in which case the `ofType` operator in your epics will choke because it only works on those POJO actions `{ type: string }`.

---

Sorry I can't help more specifically, it's tough to follow what the intent is.

e.g. this `await rootEpics(epic, id)` seems odd as rootEpics is the root epic and expects the arguments to be `(action$, store)` and UI components should not directly call epics?

Comment: yes, i myself were a bit confused about the implementation of dispatch and epics here, as i was only using the nextjs example (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-observable), and i figure not to change any of the original code. I did try calling `dispatch(startFetchingCharacters())` without calling the epics, but it doesnt seem to call `startFetchingCharactersEpic ` since `actions.fetchCharacter()` is not dispatched, am i writing the `startFetchingCharactersEpic` wrong? ps: thank you for pointing "UI components should not directly call epics" out